# WSO2ESB - Manage fault with message processor SamplingProcessor implementation

Tags: wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB, I created a proxy service that pushs the incoming messages to a message store. Then I define a message processor on that message store, to consume messages and send them to a sequence. To be able to define a sequence in my message processor, I have to use sampling processor implementation.

But I also want to manage faults on the sequence. Unfortunately, the sampling processor implementation does not provide fault management through a fault sequence. Only forwarding processor implementation allows me to manage faults, but it only manages forwarding messages to an endpoint.

How can I have both incoming messages sequence and fault sequence in a message processor ? Must I implement my own message processor ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forwarding processor and configure your endpoint to send the message to a proxy inside the ESB.

Inside this proxy, you define the mediation you want to apply to the message and send back a response to commit or rollback the transaction (commit = message removed from store  ;  rollback = message stay in the store)

responses with HTTP Satus code 200 or 500 (SOAP Fault) will be considered as good responses and will commit the transaction (the reply sequence will be executed)

responses with others HTTP Status code will be considered as fault responses and will rollback the transaction (the fault sequence will be executed)